# Get HTML input into jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get an HTML input variable into javascript function and can't figure out how to do it. The javascript is for [TimeMap](https://code.google.com/p/timemap/). The relevant HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword_search" class="form-control">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" onClick="getResult()">
```

And the javascript I have so far looks like this.

```
function getResult(){
    var keyword = $("#keyword_search").val();
    return(keyword);
}

$(function () {

    var keyword = getResult();

    tm = TimeMap.init({
        mapId: "map",               // Id of map div element (required)
        timelineId: "timeline",     // Id of timeline div element (required)
        options: {
            eventIconPath: "../static/images/"
        },
        datasets: [
            {
                title: "JSON String Dataset",
                type: "custom",

                options: {
                    // json file
                    url: "articles/filter/?keyword=" + keyword
                }
            }
        ],

        bandIntervals: [
            Timeline.DateTime.MONTH,
            Timeline.DateTime.YEAR
        ]
    });
});
```

Basically I need to get the keyword from the HTML input onto the end of the url. This will then return some JSON. Any help much appreciated and let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!!

UPDATE! The whole javascript!

```
function getResult(){
    var keyword = $("#keyword_search").val();
    return(keyword);
}

    $(function () {

        TimeMap.loaders.custom = function (options) {
            var loader = new TimeMap.loaders.remote(options);
            loader.parse = JSON.parse;
            loader.preload = function (data) {
                return data["results"]
            };
            loader.transform = function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return {
                    "title": data.text,
                    "start": data.date,
                    "options": {
                        "description": data.bicyclistCount
                    },
                    "point": {
                        "lat": data.Lat,
                        "lon": data.Lon
                    }
                };
            };
            return loader;
        };

        $("select[type=button]").click(function () {
            var keyword = getResult();



            tm = TimeMap.init({
                mapId: "map",               // Id of map div element (required)
                timelineId: "timeline",     // Id of timeline div element (required)
                options: {
                    eventIconPath: "../static/images/"
                },
                datasets: [
                    {
                        title: "JSON String Dataset",
                        type: "custom",

                        options: {
                            // json file
                            url: "articles/filter/?keyword=" + keyword
                        }
                    }
                ],

                bandIntervals: [
                    Timeline.DateTime.MONTH,
                    Timeline.DateTime.YEAR

                ]
                });
            });
        });

        SimileAjax.History.enabled = false;
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: @pingul The return from `getResult()` doesn't seem to be assigned to `var keyword` and I'm not sure how to get it to be so.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so I could be doing it all wrong!

Comment: Do you get any value in `getResult`? E.g. try to write `console.log(keyword)` in your `getResult`.

Comment: I get value from the `getResult()` function, but not when I try to call this in `var keyword` further down.

Comment: Hmm... And what if you `console.log(keyword)` after you called it in the function? Is it empty there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84392/discussion-between-sammy88888888-and-pingul).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you try to trigger the fetch, as you only have `onClick=getResult()` which itself doesn't do anything (it only returns the value of the input). Instead you should load the map when you hit the submit button:

```
$(function() {

    // You should maybe put an ID on the button as well to select it
    $("select[type=button]").click(function() {
        var keyword = getResult();
        tm = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm tried to implement your suggestions but now the map is't loading. I've updated the above to show you all the javascript.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TimeMap so can't say too much about it, and you should ask another question about it if you can't get it to work. Do you get any response into `tm`?

Comment: The map loads ok, up to the point of your suggestion above, but obviously without the keyword being returned. Yeah, might ask another question and see if I get anywhere. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With the new JS, your `getResult()`function is not very useful.
Add an id to the button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" id='search'>
```

And change the click function:

```
$("#search").click(function () {
    var keyword = $("#keyword_search").val();
    ...
}
```

Also, I'm assuming you created the `tm` variable globally?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but instead just a get a `getResult() is not defined` error. And, yeah `tm` is defined globally. Sorry, I forgot to put in the posted code.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. You should not use your `getResult()` function, just replace `var keyword = getResult()` with what I posted

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't the html button need some way to send the input the the keyword variable? In most cases I've seen that's by referencing a function in within the button tag.

Comment: You are calling two functions when you click the button right now, `getResult()` and the `click` handler. You don't need the `getResult()` because you can reference the input directly in your handler

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but still not getting anywhere. Nothing's coming through when I use `console.log()` and there's no errors in the console either. Could you give an example of the HTML and javascript?

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5p34voyt/1/) this shows that keyword has the value you need. You are probably not selecting the button the right way, you should add an ID

Comment: great, that's done it...but now the map only displays after the click...but that's for another question. thanks a lot!